# losetup -l doesn't show anything

Tags: kernel, loop-device

```
root@home-1:~# losetup -l
root@home-1:~# losetup -a -l
root@home-1:~# losetup -l /dev/loop0
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE               DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /root/test-dir/file.img   0     512
```

The system:

- Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (dedicated server)
- losetup from util-linux 2.34
- kernel 5.4.0-139-generic #156-Ubuntu SMP

What could be the cause of such behavior of losetup?

PS. for example, on another Debian 11 system `losetup -l` works as expected (4.19.0-19-amd64 kernel and there the `loop` module is built as ko module, not a builtin).

Comment: This is a Ubuntu system not Debian.

Comment: @David huh? I explicitly stated this is an issue on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: I was pointing out that something that happens on Debian may not happen on Ubuntu.